# Why was it said by the plague of Dever that it was very hard? All of them were

Tags: passover, plagues-makkos, va-eira

I would not think Dever was the hardest compared to any of the others. Aside I think chosehch some say was the hardest. But what does it mean Dever was very hard

Comment: Hi Ed. Where does it say that?

Comment: It only says: "a very grievous plague." in Exodus 9:3. Where did you read/heard this?

Comment: Or "a very heavy case of the plague", vs. a milder case ...

Comment: In the hagaddah. It says dever was very hard.

Comment: The question – I believe – refers to 9:14 (כל מגפותי אל לבך). Note that it doesn't say this regarding "dever". It says regarding "barad", but it indeed mentions "dever". From this I would assume that this was a threat, a pestilence against human (not animals!) that never came to realization. As indicated also by the very next pasuk (9:16).

Comment: The wording of כבד מאד appears not only with דבר but also for ברד and ארבה

Comment: The only other normal occurrence in the plagues was locusts. Perhaps locusts was at a normal level of devastation but dever was at a level that far surpassed normal.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't seen it in a while, I believe Rav Chaim Kanievsky's Derech Sicha quotes a Midrash explaining that the plague of dever accompanied every other plague, making it an especially difficult one to handle. (See here where the author quotes the [Orchas Chaim](https://kolhaseridim.blogspot.com/2016/04/the-eleventh-plague.html) who suggests the same idea.)

Comment: Netziv says this as well in his Imrei Shefer ... there were "aftershocks" of disease after every plague.